# How can I synchronise the scrolling between a UITableView inside of a UICollectionViewCell (Inside a UICollectionViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Currently, I am trying to synchronise the scrolling between a UITableView nested inside of a UICollectionViewCell

My view hierarchy is something like:

- UICollectionViewController

  - UICollectionView

    - UICollectionReusableView (Header view)
    - UICollectionViewCell

      - UITableView

        - UITableViewCell

What I am trying to achieve, is a view pager like effect where you are able to swipe between the pages and when you scroll vertically, the rest of the view .i.e. the navigation bar responds to it gracefully.

What I am doing right now, is getting the `contentOffset.y` of the `UITableView` and updating the `UICollectionView` content offset accordingly.

I'm using NSNotificationCenter to notify the parent ViewController when the tableview is scrolled.

```
@objc private func didScroll(_ notification: NSNotification) {
   guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: CGPoint] else { return }
   guard let offset = userInfo["offset"] else { return }

   let y = offset.y
   collectionView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), animated: false)
}
```

The outcome looks like this:

[image]

The main issue is:

1. You aren't able to swipe left or right because the content offset x is static and set to 0
2. The view sort of rolls up into itself which looks terrible
3. It's extremely glitchy

Before I tried that, my view ended up looking like this:

[image]

Here you can see the issue I described, the view not responding to the UITableView scroll.

> So to cut it short, I need to:
>
> **Find out how to make a UICollectionView scroll in sync to a UITableView inside of a UICollectionViewCell (and allow changing the
>   content offset.x)**

Comment: Have you tried disabling scrolling if you reach the end of one?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution that worked well I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use method of nested UICollectionView/UITableView and think it is difficult to resolve scrolling synchronization between two UIScrollView. Here is another method: Keep one ListView(UICollectionView or UITableView) and add swipe gesture to implement horizontal scrolling for pagination with another ListView which displays partial list data. After pagination, refresh the main ListView to show new category data.

### 1. Customize UICollectionViewLayout to offset the cell view for paging:

```
// CollectionViewPagingLayout.h
@interface UICollectionViewPagingLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger pagingSection;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint pagingOffset;

@end

// CollectionViewPagingLayout.m
// The new InvalidationContext contains new flag, invalidatedOffset, to indicates that it is just offset change and doesn't need full layout 
@interface UICollectionViewPagingLayoutInvalidationContext : UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL invalidateOffset; // Paging Or Sticky

@end

@interface UICollectionViewPagingLayout()
{
    BOOL m_layoutInvalidated; // Should be initialized to NO
}

@end

@implementation UICollectionViewPagingLayoutInvalidationContext

@end
@implementation UICollectionViewPagingLayout
@synthesize pagingOffset = m_pagingOffset;
@synthesize pagingSection = m_pagingSection;

// Skip initialization here...

+ (Class)invalidationContextClass
{
    return [UICollectionViewPagingLayoutInvalidationContext class];
}

- (void)setPagingOffset:(CGPoint)pagingOffset
{
    m_pagingOffset = pagingOffset;
    [self invalidateOffset];
}

- (void)setPagingSection:(NSInteger)pagingSection
{
    m_pagingSection = pagingSection;
    [self invalidateOffset];
}

- (void)invalidateOffset
{
    UICollectionViewPagingLayoutInvalidationContext *context = (UICollectionViewPagingLayoutInvalidationContext *)[[[UICollectionViewPagingLayout invalidationContextClass] alloc] init];
    context.invalidateOffset = YES;
    [self invalidateLayoutWithContext:context];
}

- (void)prepareLayout
{
    if (m_layoutInvalidated)
    {
        [super prepareLayout];
        m_layoutInvalidated = NO;
    }
}

- (void)invalidateLayout
{
    m_layoutInvalidated = YES;
    [super invalidateLayout];   
}

- (void)invalidateLayoutWithContext:(UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext *)context
{
    if ([context isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewPagingLayout invalidationContextClass]])
    {
        UICollectionViewPagingLayoutInvalidationContext *pagingInvalidationContext = (UICollectionViewPagingLayoutInvalidationContext *)context;
        if (!pagingInvalidationContext.invalidateOffset)
        {
            // It is not caused by internal offset change, should call prepareLayout
            m_layoutInvalidated = YES;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // It is not caused by offset change, should call prepareLayout
        m_layoutInvalidated = YES;
    }
    [super invalidateLayoutWithContext:context];
}

- (NSArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *layoutAttributesArray = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    // PagingOffset
    if (m_pagingSection != NSNotFound && !CGPointEqualToPoint(m_pagingOffset, CGPointZero))
    {
        for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes in layoutAttributesArray)
        {
            if (layoutAttributes.indexPath.section >= m_pagingSection)
            {
                layoutAttributes.frame = CGRectOffset(layoutAttributes.frame, m_pagingOffset.x, m_pagingOffset.y);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return layoutAttributesArray;
}
```

### 2. PageingCollectionView class implements the gesture:

```
// PagingCollectionView.h
// Define a protocol so that subclass can provide necessary information, such as current page, page size, the views for next page,
@protocol UIPagingCollectionViewDelegate<NSObject>
@optional

- (BOOL)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView pagingShouldBeginAtLocation:(CGPoint)location withTranslation:(CGPoint)translation andVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity onSection:(out NSInteger *_Nullable)section;
- (NSInteger)pageForSection:(NSInteger)section inPagingCollectionView:(nonnull UIPagingCollectionView *)pagingCollectionView;
- (NSInteger)pageSizeForSection:(NSInteger)section inPagingCollectionView:(nonnull UIPagingCollectionView *)pagingCollectionView;
- (nullable __kindof UIView *)pagingCollectionView:(nonnull UIPagingCollectionView *)pagingCollectionView viewForPage:(NSInteger)page;
- (void)collectionView:(nonnull UIPagingCollectionView *)pagingCollectionView pagingWithOffset:(CGPoint) offset decelerating:(BOOL)decelerating;
/ Notify subclass the paging action is completed, subclass should check if page is changed with necessary actions, for example, switch page on main collectionview, remove the collections on the left/right side, etc..
- (void)collectionView:(nonnull UIPagingCollectionView *)pagingCollectionView pagingEnded toNewPage:(NSInteger)page;

@end


@interface UIPagingCollectionView : UICollectionView

@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id <UIPagingCollectionViewDelegate> pagingDelegate;

- (void)enablePagingWithDirection:(UICollectionViewScrollDirection)direction;

@end

// PagingCollectionView.m
@interface UIPagingCollectionView() <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer          *m_swipeGuestureRecognizer;
    UICollectionViewScrollDirection m_swipeDirection;   // Should provide a public property to update for subclass

    // subclass should has a strong reference and destroy it once pagination is completed and main collection finishes to load the data of new page
    __weak UIView                   *m_leftView;
    __weak UIView                   *m_rightView;
    CGRect                          m_originalLeftFrame;
    CGRect                          m_originalRightFrame;
}

@end

@implementation UIPagingCollectionView
@synthesize pagingDelegate = m_pagingDelegate;

- (void)enablePagingWithDirection:(UICollectionViewScrollDirection)direction
{
    if (nil == m_swipeGuestureRecognizer)
    {
        m_swipeGuestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
        m_swipeGuestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:m_swipeGuestureRecognizer];
    }
    m_swipeDirection = direction;
}

- (void)offsetPagingViews:(CGPoint)offset
{
    if (nil != m_leftView)
    {
        m_leftView.frame = CGRectOffset(m_originalLeftFrame, offset.x, offset.y);
    }
    if (nil != m_rightView)
    {
        m_rightView.frame = CGRectOffset(m_originalRightFrame, offset.x, offset.y);
    }
}

- (void)handleSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == m_swipeGuestureRecognizer)
    {
        switch(m_swipeGuestureRecognizer.state)
        {
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            {
                CGPoint location =[m_swipeGuestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
                CGPoint translation =[m_swipeGuestureRecognizer translationInView:self];
                CGPoint velocity =[m_swipeGuestureRecognizer velocityInView:self];
                
                BOOL shouldBegin = NO;
                NSInteger section = NSNotFound;
                if ([self.pagingDelegate collectionView:self pagingShouldBeginAtLocation:location withTranslation:translation andVelocity:velocity onSection:&section])
                {
                    shouldBegin = YES;
                }

                if (shouldBegin)
                {
                    NSInteger page = [m_pagingDelegate pageForSection:section inPagingCollectionView:self];
                    NSInteger pageSize = [m_pagingDelegate pageSizeForSection:section inPagingCollectionView:self];
                    
                    // m_swipingContext.leftOrRight = (translation.x < 0);
                    BOOL leftOrRight = ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) && (velocity.x < 0)) || ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) && (velocity.y < 0));
                    
                    // Check validation of newPage... 
                    
                    [self buildViewForNewPage:leftOrRight ? (page + 1) : (page - 1) withCurrentPage:page];
                    
                    CGPoint offset = (m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) ? CGPointMake(translation.x, 0) : CGPointMake(0, translation.y);
                    [self pagingWithOffset:offset decelerating:NO andBindingPagingViews:YES];
                    
                    // Add a flag to tell UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged and UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded that paging gesture is valid.
                }
            }
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            {
                if (/*the flag of paging gesture is valid*/)
                {
                    CGPoint translation = [m_swipeGuestureRecognizer translationInView:self];
                    
                    if (((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) && (translation.x == 0)) || ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) && (translation.y == 0)))
                    {
                        // NO Movement
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BOOL leftOrRight = ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) && (translation.x < 0)) || ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) && (translation.y < 0));
                        
                        [self buildViewForNewPage:leftOrRight ? (page + 1) : (page - 1) withCurrentPage:page];
                    }
                    
                    CGPoint offset = (m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) ? CGPointMake(translation.x, 0) : CGPointMake(0, translation.y);
                    [self pagingWithOffset:offset decelerating:NO andBindingPagingViews:YES];
                }
            }
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            {
                if (nil != m_pagingContext)
                {
                    CGPoint translation = [m_swipeGuestureRecognizer translationInView:self];
                    
                    CGPoint offset = (m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) ? CGPointMake(translation.x, 0) : CGPointMake(0, translation.y);
                    [self pagingWithOffset:offset decelerating:NO andBindingPagingViews:YES];
                    
                    if (((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) && (translation.x == 0)) || ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) && (translation.y == 0)))
                    {
                        // NO Movement, everything is as same as old, just notify subclass
                        [m_pagingDelegate collectionView:self pagingEnded toNewPage:page];
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    BOOL leftOrRight = ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) && (translation.x < 0)) || ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) && (translation.y < 0));
                    
                    // Check （translation + sliding distance） is greater than half of size, if it is, start a sliding animation to complete the pagination and show new page
                    [m_pagingDelegate collectionView:self pagingEnded toNewPage:newPage];
                    // Otherwise, also start a sliding animation to move the current page to original position
                    [m_pagingDelegate collectionView:self pagingEnded toNewPage:page];
                }
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)pagingWithOffset:(CGPoint)offset decelerating:(BOOL)decelerating andBindingPagingViews:(BOOL)bindingPagingViews
{   
    if ([m_pagingDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIPagingCollectionViewDelegate)] && [m_pagingDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:pagingWithOffset:decelerating:)])
    {
        [self.pagingDelegate collectionView:self pagingWithOffset:offset decelerating:decelerating];
    }
    
    if (bindingPagingViews)
    {
        [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
            if (nil != self->m_leftView)
            {
                self->m_leftView.frame = CGRectOffset(self->m_originalLeftFrame, offset.x, offset.y);
            }
            if (nil != self->m_rightView)
            {
                self->m_rightView.frame = CGRectOffset(self->m_originalRightFrame, offset.x, offset.y);
            }
        }];
    }
}

- (void)buildViewForNewPage:(UIPagingContext *)newPage withCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page
{
    // newPage < page: draging dreiction is right
    // newPage > page: draging dreiction is left
    BOOL leftOrRight = newPage > page;
    UIView * __strong *pView = leftOrRight ? (&m_leftView) : (&m_rightView);
    if (nil != *pView)
    {
        return;
    }
    CGRect * pOriginalFrame = leftOrRight ? (&m_originalLeftFrame) : (&m_originalRightFrame);

    UIView *view = [self.pagingDelegate pagingCollectionView:self viewForPage:newPage];
    CGFloat xOffset = (m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) ? (pageContext.leftOrRight ? self.bounds.size.width : -self.bounds.size.width) : 0;
    CGFloat yOffset = (m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) ? 0 : (pageContext.leftOrRight ? self.bounds.size.height : -self.bounds.size.height);
    view.frame = CGRectOffset(view.frame, xOffset, yOffset);
    *pOriginalFrame = view.frame;

    *pView = view;
    
    [self addSubview:view];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == m_swipeGuestureRecognizer)
    {
        CGPoint location =[m_swipeGuestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
        CGPoint velocity =[m_swipeGuestureRecognizer velocityInView:self];
        CGPoint translation =[m_swipeGuestureRecognizer translationInView:self];
        
        BOOL shouldBegin = NO;
        NSInteger section = NSNotFound;
        // Check direction first
        if (((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) && (fabs(velocity.x) > fabs(velocity.y))) || ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) && (fabs(velocity.y) > fabs(velocity.x))))
        {
            if ([self.pagingDelegate collectionView:self pagingShouldBeginAtLocation:location withTranslation:translation andVelocity:velocity onSection:&section])
            {
                shouldBegin = YES;
            }
        }
        
        if (shouldBegin)
        {
            NSInteger page = [m_pagingDelegate pageForSection:section inPagingCollectionView:self];
            NSInteger pageSize = [m_pagingDelegate pageSizeForSection:section inPagingCollectionView:self];
            
            
            BOOL leftOrRight = ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal) && (velocity.x < 0)) || ((m_swipeDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) && (velocity.y < 0));
            
            [self buildViewForNewPage:leftOrRight ? (page + 1) : (page - 1) withCurrentPage:page];
        }
        
        return shouldBegin;
    }
    
    return [super gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:gestureRecognizer];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(nonnull UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if ((gestureRecognizer == m_swipeGuestureRecognizer) &&
        (otherGestureRecognizer == self.panGestureRecognizer))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    
    return NO;
}

@end
```

### 3. Implements the subclass

Then we can bypass the scrolling issue between nested UIScrollViews. Completed sample code is [here](https://github.com/BlueMatthew/PagingSubList)